# How to use blazor scoped service in a class

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I am trying to use a scoped service for AuthenticationStateProvider to get user details in different classes of the solution.
The service class that is used as scoped service looks like this :

```
public class ServiceClass
{
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

    public ServiceClass(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }
    public async Task<string> GetIdentity()
    {
        var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.User;
        return user.Identity.Name;
    }}
```

I registered the class in startup as scoped service like this :

`services.AddScoped<ServiceClass>();`

Then trying to consume the service in another class DAL like this

```
 public class DAL
{

    private readonly ServiceClass userClass;
    public async Task<bool> saveBankCash(TransactionBankCashHeader master, List<TransactionBankCashDetail> lines, string Doctype)
    {


        string user = await userClass.GetIdentity();
    }
}
```

But in the saveBankCash method, userClass is null, can someone please guide me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add a constructor to DAL like this:

```
public DAL(ServiceClass s)
{
 userClass = s; 
}
```

Note that this will only work if you add DAL to the DI as well, like this:

```
services.AddScoped<DAL>();
```

The DI will then inject the dependencies in the call to the constructor.